# Apache open nlp maxent: proper method to handle 'probability distribution' labels?

Tags: java, machine-learning, opennlp, maxent

Apache open nlp maxent: is it possible to set 'probability distribution' label?

I have read football.dat, gameLocation.dat, and realTeam.data and tried CreateModel.java and Predict.java in the 'sports' package.  The prediction results are classes probability distribution like **lose[0.3686]  win[0.4416]  tie[0.1899]**, and labels of training examples at the end of lines are all single classes, like **win**.

Is it possible to set probability distribution labels like **lose[0.3686]  win[0.4416]  tie[0.1899]** in the training data? If not, beyond just setting the max probability tag as the label, what are proper ways to handle 'probability distribution' labels? For example, is duplicating examples with class labels proportional to probabilities a principled approach or not, or other systematic methods.